# A better way to dynamically fetch nested object's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Here's my functtion

```
var getLocaleDefault = function(settings){
    var defaultLocale = settings.defaultLocale;
    eval('var locale = settings.locale.'+defaultLocale);
    return locale;
}
```

settings is a `JSON.parse()`ed object of a JSON

```
{

    "classes": 8,
    "config": "classConfig",
    "locale": {
        "en": "localeEn"
    },
    "defaultLocale": "en"
}
```

As the code is: I am trying to get `object.locale.en` just because `defaultLocale` is `en`. Is there a better way other than eval to achieve what i am trying to do? Or is it the best/effective way of doing these kind of works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var locale = settings.locale[defaultLocale];
return locale;
```

Even better,

```
var getLocaleDefault = function(settings){
    return settings.locale[settings.defaultLocale];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. (I am literally laughing on myself :) )